# Recursive sequence $a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence relation  $a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2}$ and the values of $a_0$ and $a_1$. For example, $a_0=a_1=1$.

Can we give an **explicit formula** of this sequence? If yes, how to achieve that?

(In fact, I find this sequence in [Burnside's lemma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhfFfYfmMpc) which describes the number of different positions to put 8 rooks in a chessboard, and each rook should lie in different row and column. )

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is sequence [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085) in the OEIS. Looking at the formula section I doubt there is a nice closed form

Comment: $$
a_n = n!\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor } {\frac{{2^{ - k} }}{{k!(n - 2k)!}}} 
$$